# linear integral

Tags: calculus

I understand that the line integral can not always be easily obtained, not only by the parameterization of the curve but also by the vector field, example we want to calculate $\oint _{ C }^{  }{ \left( { e }^{ x }\sin { y }  \right) dx+\left( { e }^{ x }\cos { y+x }  \right) dy } $, where $C$ is the arc of the circumference ${ x }^{ 2 }+{ y }^{ 2 }=1$ in the first quadrant in the counterclockwise direction. It is not possible to integrate. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can also try using the fundamental theorem of line integrals, could be that the integrand is the gradient of a scalar function (just by inspection it looks like $f= e^x \cos{y} + \frac{1}{2} x^2 + C$) which need only be evaluated at the endpoints.

Comment: By the fundamental theorem I mean $\int_{r(a)}^{r(b)} \nabla f \cdot d r = f(r(b)) - f(r(a))$

Comment: I don't think that is the correct scalar function @Triatticus.

Comment: I unfortunately am on mobile and have no paper in front of me but you are right because the cosine will bring an additional negative

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

The integrand is
$$d (e^x\sin (y))+xdy $$
the integral is

$$1+\int_0^\frac {\pi}{2}\cos^2 (t)dt $$

Comment: That replacement I already did, but it is not possible to integrate